# Using react.js and bootstrap columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Pretty new to react. I have a bunch of divs with some content which I render from seperate jsx files. I want to place these divs across/inside three bootstrap columns. Not sure how to go about doing this, and couldn't really find anything similar.

Comment: Do you have any example code that you have tried?

Comment: No. I am able to render the divs inside a single row or a single column. Though, this causes some issues with alignment of when the divs are varying in height. Ultimately what I want to achieve is this [layout](http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html), which is why I'm thinking in columns.

Comment: Please show us some code so this question is easier to answer.